# Chrome MULTIPLE_CONTENT_LENGTH error

Tags: http, google-chrome, http-headers, chromium

If I access my page directly, I get:

```
$ wget http://localhost:8010/ --save-headers -O -
--2010-10-29 18:30:24--  http://localhost:8010/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8010... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 950 [text/html]
Saving to: `STDOUT'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gunicorn/0.11.1
Date: Fri, 29 Oct 2010 16:30:24 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie, Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 950
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en-us
```

If I access it via the cache:

```
$ wget http://localhost:8000/ --save-headers -O -
--2010-10-29 18:30:31--  http://localhost:8000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 950 [text/html]
Saving to: `STDOUT'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gunicorn/0.11.1
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie, Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en-us
Content-Length: 950
Date: Fri, 29 Oct 2010 16:30:31 GMT
X-Varnish: 818233557
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
```

When I open the latter in Chromium (8.0.552.18 (0)), I get this error:

```
Error 346 (net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_LENGTH): Unknown error.
```

I only see three extra headers; which one should I remove to make it display in Chrome?

**EDIT:** I have eventually got rid of this problem, but I can't remember how, and I don't have access to that system anymore. I'm starting a bounty, maybe somebody will explain me what was going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this version](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/http/http_stream_parser.cc?revision=60317&view=markup) of the chromium source.  It looks like if you do not specify "Transfer-Encoding" and you include multiple lengths it will throw this very error.  Later revisions added a check that the content length sizes must be different to throw this error.  Seems like it was added as a security precaution.

Probably would not have ever seen this error with a newer version of Chromium.

Comment: You're probably right here. The new versions don't complain. It looks like I cannot give you the full bounty as it has already expired, so sorry about that, but thanks very much for helping with this one.

Answer (score -1):

You might try disabling the DNS prefetching in the Chromium settings. Go to Preferences > Under the Hood and un-check "Use DNS pre-fetching to improve page load times".

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with DNS pre-fetching. My page doesn't even load. And there are no URLs on it.